# CodeLite cmake output directory configuration

Tags: configuration, cmake, directory, codelite

I've got a tiny problem here with configuring the output paths in the project settings. I'd like CodeLite to put the binary files into a folder named based on the configuration and inside a folder named bin in it, but for the life of mine I can't get it working. I simply changed every path and filename I could in the project settings under general ( I used macros exclusively like $(ProjectPath) etc. ) and after running CMake, it always puts everything inside a folder named cmake-build-Configuration (Debug or Release). I googled a LOT, maybe I just can't find the right search phrase, I've also looked at the Wiki, but couldn't find anything there what could point me in the right direction. My CMakeLists.txt for the project looks like this:

```
# -*- CMakeLists.txt generated by CodeLite IDE. Do not edit by hand -*-

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(main)

# Define some variables
set(PROJECT_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main")



#{{{{ User Code 1
# Place your code here
#}}}}

include_directories(
    .
    .

)


# Compiler options
add_definitions(-ggdb)
add_definitions(-O0)
add_definitions(-Wall)
add_definitions(-std=c++14)

# Linker options


if(WIN32)
    # Resource options
endif(WIN32)

# Library path
set(CMAKE_LDFLAGS "${CMAKE_LDFLAGS} -L. ")

# Define the CXX sources
set ( CXX_SRCS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main/src/main.cpp
)

set_source_files_properties(
    ${CXX_SRCS} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS
    " -ggdb -O0 -Wall -std=c++14")

if(WIN32)
    enable_language(RC)
    set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILE_OBJECT
        "<CMAKE_RC_COMPILER> ${RC_OPTIONS} -O coff -i <SOURCE> -o <OBJECT>")
endif(WIN32)



#{{{{ User Code 2
# Place your code here
#}}}}

add_executable(main ${RC_SRCS} ${CXX_SRCS} ${C_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(main ${LINK_OPTIONS})



#{{{{ User Code 3
# Place your code here
#}}}}
```

and this is the CMakeLists.txt for the workspace:

```
# -*- CMakeLists.txt generated by CodeLite IDE. Do not edit by hand -*-

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

# Workspace name
project(YoLoEngine)

# This setting is useful for providing JSON file used by CodeLite for code completion
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS 1)

# Set default locations
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)



#{{{{ User Code 1
# Place your code here
#}}}}

set(CONFIGURATION_NAME "Debug")



#{{{{ User Code 2
# Place your code here
#}}}}

# Projects
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main)


#{{{{ User Code 3
# Place your code here
#}}}}
```

I have to mention, that I have very very limited knowledge of CMake, I just started to learn how to use it today and several things are not clear to me. I didn't try to manipulate the above files manually, because I wanted to know how to set things up inside CodeLite.

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I've downloaded CodeLite with apt from the ubuntu repo and it's version is 10.0.0.

Thank you for your help :)

Edit 1:
I'd like to set this up using the user interface of CodeLite, not by modifying the CMakeLists.txt files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this method for copying your binary output file in some address:

after add_executable(...) just simply add this:

```
set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/YOUROUTPUT)
```

instead of YOUROUTPUT you can put some cmake variable like your project name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'd like to set this up using the user interface of CodeLite. I'll edit my question, to clear that out :) I'll save your answer and select it as the accepted one, if I don't get any closer ones.